# How to redirect to other page

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have this 8 textboxes that require users to fill in the data in it and after they had confirmed it, they will click on submit data and keep it in the database. The process is working perfectly but I just don't know how to redirecr user to next page to let tell them the 'Records are sucessfully added' . Here I paste code snippet. Hope you guys can help me. Thank you.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings       ["Connection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into......");
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", Membership.GetUser().UserName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bulan", Label1.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex1s", Label18.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1s", Label20.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex2s", Label2.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2s", Label21.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex3s", Label3.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3s", Label22.Text); 
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex4s", Label4.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4s", Label23.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex5s", Label5.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5s", Label24.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex6s", Label6.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6s", Label25.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex7s", Label7.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p7s", Label26.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ex8s", Label8.Text);     
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p8s", Label27.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@totals", Label28.Text);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Maybe [`<asp:Wizard />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/fs0za4w6.aspx) is the thing you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use if...else...
eg:

```
  int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (rowsAffected == 1)
        {
            //Success notification 
        }
        else
        {
            //Error notification 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Response.Redirect("nextPage.aspx");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options. In order of preference:

1. Modify the output of the page that's adding the records, to show the success message
2. A server-side redirect, using `Server.Transfer()`
3. Issue an HTTP redirect, using `Response.Redirect()`

Answer (score 1):

I'll complete it with:

```
[...]
conn.Close();
Response.Redirect("~/NewPage.aspx?msg=complete");
```

will complete your code (it's important to close the connection)
the Response.Redirect will send the user to the page in the method param.

on the NewPage.aspx.cs I'll then catch the url parameter:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if(Request.QueryString["msg"] != null)
        {
            litMsg.Text = "<div id='msgTxt' style='display:none;background-color:red;'>" + Request.QueryString["msg"] + "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

where litMsg is a literal control on the page. And to spice it up a little I used some JQuery on the NewPage.aspx

```
<asp:Literal ID="litMsg" Text="" runat="server" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    try {
        $("#msgTxt").fadeIn("slow");
    } catch (e) {
    //it's probably not there
    }
</script>
```

makes more sense? :)

Comment: Hi @sjums. Can u tell me how to do that step by step pls?

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1**

You could have a panel which would be hidden, and then the button could show the panel, and set the panel's text.

That should definitely work.

**Approach 2**

A different approach would be the HTML way. You could trigger the following:

```
Response.Redirect("MyPage.aspx?message=Records are successfully added");
```

And then handle that in your ASPX file:

```
<p>
<%= Request["message"] %>
</p>
```

Comment: Hi Mathias. Thanks for your answer. But can u pls tell me where to put the code? is it under the buttonevent or somewhere else?

Comment: Research doesn't harm anyone. Put the Response.Redirect in your button call. Then the other stuff in your ASPX file.